# Interpret partial autocorrelation

Tags: time-series

I am learning about ACF and PACF graphs. I am not sure I understand how to interpret the one I got for my data.
[image]

Comment: Oh noes, where are the units?

Comment: Is interpreting this for a course?

Comment: Yes it's, the graph was obtain usign matlab, the data are video frames